# Suppose that x is an integer. Use a proof by contrapositive to prove that if 5x+7 is even, then x is odd.

Tags: proof-writing

I know that we assume x is even. So, as x is even, x = 2k for some integer k.

Then, that would make for 5(2k)+7 = 10k + 7. And this is where I'm stuck. I know that it isn't complete at 10k+7 to prove that it is odd, but I do not have a clue as to what to do to bring out the 2k+1 to show that it is odd. How do I get there?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$10k+7=10k+6+1=2(5k+3)+1.$$
Since $5k+3$ is an integer, we know that $2(5k+3)$ is even and that $2(5k+3)+1$ is odd.

So, this leads that "$x\in\mathbb Z$ is even $\Rightarrow 5x+7$ is odd" is true.

Comment: That'll do it. I wish I saw that. THANK YOU!

Comment: @J-Play: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We've to prove that $5x+7$ is even $\implies$ $x$ is odd.

The contrapositive of above is: $x$ is even $\implies$ $5x+7$ is odd.

Now, since $x$ is even $x = 2k$ for some $k$.

$x = 2k \implies 5x = 10k \implies 5x+7 = 10k + 7 = \text{even number} + \text{odd number}$. Now, it is well known fact that sum of an even number and an odd number is an odd number.

Now, since the truth values of an implication and its contrapositive are equal...